# Can't shutdown app engine version. Keeps billing

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I am not able to stop and consequently delete a app engine version. I have 3 different versions at the moment, under the same default service:

1. `gappa-v1`, which is currently serving 100% of the traffic
2. `mg-v1`, which is currently stopped
3. `20170223t163224`

I am able to stop, restart and delete all the versions but the `20170223t163224` version.
I have tried everything, both from the Google Cloud Console, and the `gcloud` command-line tool.
Interacting from the Google Cloud Console is kinda useless because it gives me no feedback on the error, but just a generic **Failed to stop version** on a stop attemp or **The version could not be deleted** on a delete attempt.

When interacting with the `gcloud` command line tool, I have tried:

```
$> gcloud app versions stop `20170223t163224`
$> ERROR: (gcloud.app.versions.stop) INTERNAL: This flexible version cannot be modified, it can only be deleted.
```

Then if I try to delete it:

```
$> gcloud app versions delete `20170223t163224`
$> [default/20170223t163224]: Error Response: [13] Deployment Manager operation failed, name: operation-1488895382516-54a247861f121-d456a139-0b1e3fc6, error: [{"code":"RESOURCE_ERROR","locati
on":"/deployments/aef-default-20170223t163224/resources/aef-default-20170223t163224-00","message":"{\"ResourceType\":\"compute.beta.regionInstanceGroupManager\",\"ResourceErrorCode\":\"400
\",\"ResourceErrorMessage\":{\"code\":400,\"errors\":[{\"domain\":\"global\",\"message\":\"The instance_group_manager resource 'aef-default-20170223t163224-00' is already being used by 'ae
f-default-20170223t163224'\",\"reason\":\"resourceInUseByAnotherResource\"}],\"message\":\"The instance_group_manager resource 'aef-default-20170223t163224-00' is already being used by 'ae
f-default-20170223t163224'\",\"statusMessage\":\"Bad Request\",\"requestPath\":\"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/MYAPPID/regions/us-central1/instanceGroupMana
gers/aef-default-20170223t163224-00\"}}"}]
```

Somewhere (I can't find where in this moment), the docs says I can't delete a version until traffic is allocated to it. So, I made sure that the version has no traffic allocated. Infact the app engine console shows the following:

[image: Traffic allocation and instances]

I have also tried to delete the single version instances using `gcloud app instances delete INSTANCE_ID --service=default --version=20170223t163224. This command didn't return any error, but had no effect, there are still 2 instances.

I also tried to override the version deploying a new, basically empty app (hello world, from [the google tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples)), but it didn't allow me to deploy it.

**The biggest problem** is that i am still getting charged for this version, as it is still there, serving and with 2 instances.

I am currently working with Google App Engine Flexible Environment and NodeJS.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have been charged for more than 5 days and the support is not helping me, a lady in the google cloud support told me "delete the project" but if I do it, I will lose all my firebase work.

Comment: Hi @JancoBoscan, my solution was actually to go through the support. Yes, it took a little while but they were able to fix it, and I got all the money back that I have spent since the problem occurred. All I can say is to go through them.

You problem seems different than what I had, because I actually had to delete, while it looks like you don't want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should contact billing through [this form](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing). In future, for production issues like this, you should also see about posting to the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).