# Deleting old version of GAE application is failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine

I want to delete old version of GAE application, but deleting operation always fails since 5 months ago.

The error message is 'There is an operation pending for this application. Please wait and try again'.

I think it's inappropriate that we are charged to unnecessary instances and we couldn't delete these instances.

---

## **Technical details**

#### **GCP Console(GUI)**

screenshot: https://gyazo.com/edcb1968944867c2a6a029efa7bf5bb5

Deleting the version from this page is failed.

The error message is 'There is an operation pending for this application. Please wait and try again'.

Stoping the version from this page is also failed.

The error message is 'This flexible version cannot be modified, it can only be deleted. Please re-deploy the version.'

#### **CLI**

Result when deleting version from CLI. (Occured internal error)

```sh
# https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/versions/delete
$ gcloud app versions delete 20191028t001234
Deleting the following versions:
 - my-project/default/20191028t001234
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

Deleting [default/20191028t001234]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.versions.delete) Issue deleting version: [default/20191028t001234]

[default/20191028t001234]: Error Response: [13] Flex operation projects/my-project/regions/asia-northeast1/operations/aab27279-89bf-4deb-aecd-d25352977d11 error [INTERNAL]: An internal error occurred while processing task /appengine-flex-v1/delete_flex_deployment/flex_delete_resources>2020-01-06T11:26:23.364Z38645.oj.0: Deployment Manager operation my-project/operation-1578309983602-59b76edeb0758-e471c6e1-71f4fbeb errors: [code: "RESOURCE_ERROR"
location: "/deployments/aef-default-20191028t001234/resources/aef-default-20191028t001234-hcs"
message: "{\"ResourceType\":\"compute.v1.httpsHealthCheck\",\"ResourceErrorCode\":\"400\",\"ResourceErrorMessage\":{\"code\":400,\"errors\":[{\"domain\":\"global\",\"message\":\"The https_health_check resource \'projects/my-project/global/httpsHealthChecks/aef-default-20191028t001234-hcs\' is already being used by \'projects/my-project/global/backendServices/aef-default-20191028t001234-bs\'\",\"reason\":\"resourceInUseByAnotherResource\"}],\"message\":\"The https_health_check resource \'projects/my-project/global/httpsHealthChecks/aef-default-20191028t001234-hcs\' is already being used by \'projects/my-project/global/backendServices/aef-default-20191028t001234-bs\'\",\"statusMessage\":\"Bad Request\",\"requestPath\":\"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project/global/httpsHealthChecks/aef-default-20191028t001234-hcs\",\"httpMethod\":\"DELETE\"}}"
, code: "RESOURCE_ERROR"
location: "/deployments/aef-default-20191028t001234/resources/aef-default-20191028t001234-00"
message: "{\"ResourceType\":\"compute.beta.regionInstanceGroupManager\",\"ResourceErrorCode\":\"400\",\"ResourceErrorMessage\":{\"code\":400,\"errors\":[{\"domain\":\"global\",\"message\":\"The instance_group_manager resource \'projects/my-project/regions/asia-northeast1/instanceGroupManagers/aef-default-20191028t001234-00\' is already being used by \'projects/my-project/global/backendServices/aef-default-20191028t001234-bs\'\",\"reason\":\"resourceInUseByAnotherResource\"}],\"message\":\"The instance_group_manager resource \'projects/my-project/regions/asia-northeast1/instanceGroupManagers/aef-default-20191028t001234-00\' is already being used by \'projects/my-project/global/backendServices/aef-default-20191028t001234-bs\'\",\"statusMessage\":\"Bad Request\",\"requestPath\":\"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/my-project/regions/asia-northeast1/instanceGroupManagers/aef-default-20191028t001234-00\",\"httpMethod\":\"DELETE\"}}"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, it's recommended for you to reach out directly to Google Cloud Platform Suppor Team directly - you can contact them [here](https://cloud.google.com/support). As per other cases, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42651008/cant-shutdown-app-engine-version-keeps-billing), they will be able to better assist you regarding payment - since you are unable to delete a version that you are not using and it's being billed for it - and should be able to help you fix the issue and delete it.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Actually I've already asked question to support team by free account and he recommended use stackoverflow or use paid support.

I'll use paid service. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds great! Thanks for letting me know @KatsumaNarisawa!